# Question about Moneros privacy

Tags: privacy

I searched a lot, but I can't find an answer to my question. If I send one Monero from wallet A to wallet B. Is it possible to find out how long I was holding this one Monero in wallet A? That's not possible, right? Because you can't even get any information on the sender from wallet A, right?

Thanks for any input regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is correct. Only thing that is known is, that there was some transaction. Nobody can tell from which wallet to which other wallet, who did it, which amount was involved and you cant tell the balances of any of the wallets. Not even if a wallet send coins or received coins.

You can basically tell nothing about any transaction. You can just count them without knowing any meaningful context about them.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Can I somehow find out the block number of a transaction and at least guess when it was done?

Comment: @nomak23 -  You can enter the transaction hash on a block explorer like, for instance, [XMRchain](https://xmrchain.net) and see the block height and (approximate) date.

Comment: Let's assume I bought one Monero a week ago. Then I send this one Monero from wallet A to wallet B. Can somone find out when I bought the Monero in wallet B?

Comment: No because nobody knows that you are the owner of the wallet. Also, a second no, because you can not tell if you received a monero or if you spend a monero